# Numpy: concatenation and sorting of matrices

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following problem: I have two vectors containing time moments:

```
a = np.array((0.23, 1.70))
a_ = np.array((0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2))
```

and two vectors corresponding to the values ​​of the function at these points of time

```
b = np.array((3, -1.2))
b_ = np.array((0, 3, 3, 3, -1.2))
```

It want to combine the vectors `a, a_` and `b, b_` into one and sort the time in ascending order. The final effect should look like this:

```
A = np.array((0, 0.23, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 1.70, 2))
B = np.array((0, 3, 3, 3, 3, -1.2, -1.2))
```

How to do it? Because here I gave a simple example, but in general I will work with longer vectors. I thought to connect the vectors `a, a_` and `b, b_`, then make them a matrix and sort them over time (i.e. the first row), but if I sort after the first row, the values in the second row doesnt change their position :(  Then I also want to access them and count the differences between successive elements (time and value increments)

Comment: how do you want the final answer to look like? Aren't A and B what you need ?

Comment: What happened when you tried putting `numpy concatenate arrays` into a search engine? Howa bout `numpy sort array`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I tried, I first convert them into key value pairs and then sort them based on the keys.
Here's the Code:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array((0.23, 1.70))
a_ = np.array((0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2))

b = np.array((3, -1.2))
b_ = np.array((0, 3, 3, 3, -1.2))

sol = {}
for i, j in zip(list(a), list(b)):
    sol[i] = j

for i, j in zip(list(a_), list(b_)):
    sol[i] = j

sol = dict(sorted(sol.items(), key = lambda kv:(kv[0], kv[1])))
A = np.array(list(sol.keys()))
B = np.array(list(sol.values()))

print(f'{A}\n{B}')
```

Result:

```
[0.   0.23 0.5  1.   1.5  1.7  2.  ]
[ 0.   3.   3.   3.   3.  -1.2 -1.2]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I'm curious if it can be done more simply